# my firefox extension wont load in the browser toolbar

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-addon, toolbar

I recently created a quick launch extension for personal use. it was accepted by firefox to be on their add-ons platform successfully, but when i downloaded it and tried to open it in the toolbar, i was greeted with the following message: "can't read and change data on this site". i LITERALLY don't know what to do. i tried fixing the manifest doc but it didnt work. can someone take a look at my code and please tell me where i went wrong:

P.S as you can tell, im a noob

img:[this is the message the extension currently gives me when i try to use it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nT68.png)

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Yalwa Launcher</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
        html, body{
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            margin: 0;
            min-height: 180px;
            padding: 0;
            width: 384px;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        h1{
            font-family: 'Menlo', monospace;
            font-size: 22px;
            font-weight: 400;
            margin: 0;
            color: #2f5876;
        }

        a:link, a:visited{
            color: #000;
            outline: 0;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        img{
            width: 30px;
        }

        .modal-header{
            text-align: center;
            align-items: center;
            border-bottom: 0.5px solid #dadada;
        }

        .modal-content{
            text-align: center;
            padding: 0 22px;
            color: rgb(245, 161, 4);
        }

        .modal-icons{
            border-top: 0.5px solid #dadada;
            height: 50px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .logo{
            padding: 16px;
        }

        .logo-icon{
            vertical-align: text-bottom;
            margin-right: 12px;
        }

        .version{
            color: rgb(98, 16, 252);
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        .flex-container{
            text-align: center;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding: 10px 22px;
        }

        .flex{
            opacity: 1;
            transition: opacity 0.2 ease-in-out;
            width: 120px;
        }

        .flex:hover{
            opacity: 0.5;
        }

        .flex .fa{
            font-size: 40px;
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(20, 4, 253)), to(rgba(15, 147, 255, 0.685)));
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            background-clip: text;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
            display: initial; /* reset Font Awesome's display:inline-block */

        }

    </style>

<div class="modal-header">
    <h1 class="logo">
      <img src="images/yalwa_logo.png.png" alt="Yalwa Launcher" class="logo-icon">YALWA Launcher <span class="version">1.1.0</span>
    </h1>
  </div> 
  <div class="modal-content">
    <p>Express YALWA Launcher</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-icons">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex">
        <a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">
          <i class="fa fa-adn"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="flex">
        <a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">
          <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="flex">
        <a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">
          <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
```

If you need to see the manifes.json, just let me know, thanks!

i wanted the extension to open up to display the options coded in it, just like the photo above[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpc6P.jpg)